# Why does .Net change the Process.MainWindowHandle?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, process

I created a new Windows Forms App in Visual Studio and added the following code to it:

```
new Form1().Show();
```

By calling this code, the `Process.MainWindowHandle` of my process, reported by `Process.GetProcessById(Environment.ProcessId).MainWindowHandle` will be changed to the new Form.

But if I activate the first created form again, the `MainWindowHandle` will be reported with the initially created form. So, if I'm right, the `Process.MainWindowHandle` always reports the active form handle and not the initially created form.

I've also tried to use a `ApplicationContext` with defining its `MainForm` property, but this does not change anything.

How and I define a `MainForm` in .Net with C#, which handles will be reported by `Process.MainWindowHandle` always, independent if it's active or hidden?

Comment: `MainWindowHandle` was a monumental mistake. It is a concept purely made up by the BCL. There is no reflection of this concept in the window manager implementation. You're going to have to live with the heuristics deployed by .NET's implementation or choose a more tractable solution to identifying a particular window of interest.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you want to access a form outside of the process, I suggest you to use `FindWindowEx`.

Comment: `FindWindowEx()` doesn't reliably work with Windows Forms windows, as the framework dynamically generates the class names.

Comment: If it's about an application you own, you could call `RegisterWindowMessage`, to register a custom message, and make all top-level windows of your application always respond with the handle of the starting Form -- If you specify why and when you need this information, you may get more *focused* suggestions

Comment: `Application.OpenForms[0]` usually returns the main form, i.e., the first form that was opened. but you could also keep a reference to your main form to access it, e.g. through a public static field or property in the `Program` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the comments to my question, I found this solution to get the handle of my MainForm:

With this code, I will find a windows handle of a process, which answers to a user defined Windows message:

```
IntPtr mainFormHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
foreach (ProcessThread thread in Process.GetProcessById(processId).Threads)
    EnumThreadWindows(
        (uint)thread.Id,
        (hWnd, lParam) =>
        {
            if (SendMessage(hWnd, WM_USER, 0, 0) == TRUE)
                mainFormHandle = hWnd;
            return TRUE;
        },
        0);
```

... if the MainForm was found, the `mainFormHandle` is set to it's handle.

To use this code, my MainForm has to answer the sent Windows message:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_USER)
        m.Result = TRUE;
    else
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a statically available `Map` between names and windows. So, if you want to perform something on a specific window, then you would be able to load that window by name from this `Map`. This of course means that whenever a window is created, it needs to be reflected into this Map and whenever a window is disposed of, then the Map needs to be adjusted as well.

As about your actual question, look at this resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle?view=net-8.0

particularly this part:

> The main window is the window opened by the process that currently has the focus (the TopLevel form). You must use the Refresh method to refresh the Process object to get the most up to date main window handle if it has changed. In general, because the window handle is cached, use Refresh beforehand to guarantee that you'll retrieve the current handle.

So, whatever refreshes the [TopLevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.toplevel?view=windowsdesktop-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-8.0) property by focusing the form, such as the `Show` method that you called will change the main window handle accordingly. If you expect something different to occur instead, then you will need to implement that logic yourself.